# Filtering a map based on expected keys

Tags: clojure, hashmap, destructuring

In my Clojure webapp I have various model namespaces with functions that take a map as an agrument and somehow insert that map into a database. I would like to be able take out only the desired keys from the map before I do the insert.

A basic example of this is:

```
(let [msg-keys [:title :body]
      msg {:title "Hello" :body "This is an example" :somekey "asdf" :someotherkey "asdf"}]
  (select-keys msg msg-keys))

;; => {:title "Hello" :body "This is an example"}
```

`select-keys` is not an option when the map is somewhat complex and I would like to select a specific set of nested keys:

```
(let [person {:name {:first "john" :john "smith"} :age 40 :weight 155 :something {:a "a" :b "b" :c "c" :d "d"}}]
  (some-select-key-fn person [:name [:first] :something [:a :b]]))

;; => {:name {:first "john"} :something {:a "a" :b "b"}}
```

Is there a way to do this with the core functions? Is there a way do this purely with destructuring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This topic was [discussed in the Clojure Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/clojure/gGigc9BWzNw) along with a few solutions.

Destructuring is probably the closest to a "core" capability, and may be a fine solution if your problem is rather static and the map has all of the expected keys (thus avoiding `nil`). It could look like:

```
(let [person {:name {:first "john" :john "smith"} :age 40 :weight 155 :something {:a "a" :b "b" :c "c" :d "d"}}
      {{:keys [first]} :name {:keys [a b]} :something} person]
  {:name {:first first} :something {:a a :b b}})
;; => {:name {:first "john"}, :something {:a "a", :b "b"}}
```

Below is a survey of the solutions in the Clojure Google Group thread, applied to your sample map. They each have a different take on how to specify the nested keys to be selected.

Here is [Christophe Grand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97592)'s [solution](https://gist.github.com/cgrand/2823916):

```
(defprotocol Selector
  (-select [s m]))

(defn select [m selectors-coll]
  (reduce conj {} (map #(-select % m) selectors-coll)))

(extend-protocol Selector
  clojure.lang.Keyword
  (-select [k m]
    (find m k))
  clojure.lang.APersistentMap
  (-select [sm m]
    (into {}
          (for [[k s] sm]
            [k (select (get m k) s)]))))
```

Using it requires a slightly modified syntax:

```
(let [person {:name {:first "john" :john "smith"} :age 40 :weight 155 :something {:a "a" :b "b" :c "c" :d "d"}}]
  (select person [{:name [:first] :something [:a :b]}]))
;; => {:something {:b "b", :a "a"}, :name {:first "john"}}
```

Here is Moritz Ulrich's solution (he cautions that it doesn't work on maps with seqs as keys):

```
(defn select-in [m keyseq]
  (loop [acc {} [k & ks] (seq keyseq)]
    (if k
      (recur
        (if (sequential? k)
          (let [[k ks] k]
            (assoc acc k
                   (select-in (get m k) ks)))
          (assoc acc k (get m k)))
        ks)
      acc)))
```

Using it requires another slightly modified syntax:

```
(let [person {:name {:first "john" :john "smith"} :age 40 :weight 155 :something {:a "a" :b "b" :c "c" :d "d"}}]
  (select-in person [[:name [:first]] [:something [:a :b]]]))
;; => {:something {:b "b", :a "a"}, :name {:first "john"}}
```

Here is Jay Fields's solution:

```
(defn select-nested-keys [m top-level-keys & {:as pairs}]
  (reduce #(update-in %1 (first %2) select-keys (last %2)) (select-keys m top-level-keys) pairs))
```

It uses a different syntax:

```
(let [person {:name {:first "john" :john "smith"} :age 40 :weight 155 :something {:a "a" :b "b" :c "c" :d "d"}}]
  (select-nested-keys person [:name :something] [:name] [:first] [:something] [:a :b]))
;; => {:something {:b "b", :a "a"}, :name {:first "john"}}
```

Here is Baishampayan Ghose's [solution](https://www.refheap.com/2911):

```
(defprotocol ^:private IExpandable
             (^:private expand [this]))


(extend-protocol IExpandable
  clojure.lang.Keyword
  (expand [k] {k ::all})

  clojure.lang.IPersistentVector
  (expand [v] (if (empty? v)
                {}
                (apply merge (map expand v))))

  clojure.lang.IPersistentMap
  (expand [m]
    (assert (= (count (keys m)) 1) "Number of keys in a selector map can't be more than 1.")
    (let [[k v] (-> m first ((juxt key val)))]
          {k (expand v)}))

  nil
  (expand [_] {}))


(defn ^:private extract* [m selectors expand?]
  (let [sels (if expand? (expand selectors) selectors)]
    (reduce-kv (fn [res k v]
                 (if (= v ::all)
                   (assoc res k (m k))
                   (assoc res k (extract* (m k) v false))))
               {} sels)))

(defn extract
  "Like select-keys, but can select nested keys.

   Examples -

   (extract [{:b {:c [:d]}} :g] {:a 1 :b {:c {:d 1 :e 2}} :g 42 :xxx 11})
   ;=> {:g 42, :b {:c {:d 1}}}

   (extract [:g] {:a 1 :b {:c {:d 1 :e 2}} :g 42 :xxx 11})
   ;=> {:g 42}

   (extract [{:b [:c]} :xxx] {:a 1 :b {:c {:d 1 :e 2}} :g 42 :xxx 11})
   ;=> {:b {:c {:d 1, :e 2}}, :xxx 11}

   Also see - exclude"
  [selectors m]
  (extract* m selectors true))
```

It uses another syntax (and the parameters are reversed):

```
(let [person {:name {:first "john" :john "smith"} :age 40 :weight 155 :something {:a "a" :b "b" :c "c" :d "d"}}]
  (extract [{:name [:first]} {:something [:a :b]}] person))
;; => {:name {:first "john"}, :something {:a "a", :b "b"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use select keys on each nested portion of the structure.

```
(-> person
    (select-keys [:name :something])
    (update-in [:name] select-keys [:first])
    (update-in [:something] select-keys [:a :b]))
```

You could of course use a generalized version of the above to implement the syntax you suggest in a function (with a `reduce` rather than a `->` form, most likely, and recursive calls for each nested selection of keys). Destructuring would not help much, it makes binding nested data convenient, but isn't really that useful for constructing values.

Here is how I would do it with `reduce` and recursion:

```
(defn simplify
  [m skel]
  (if-let [kvs (not-empty (partition 2 skel))]
    (reduce (fn [m [k nested]]
              (if nested
                (update-in m [k] simplify nested)
                m))
            (select-keys m (map first kvs))
            kvs)
    m))
```

note that your proposed argument format is inconvenient, so I changed it slightly

```
user=> (simplify {:name {:first "john" :john "smith"}
                  :age 40
                  :weight 155
                  :something {:a "a" :b "b" :c "c" :d "d"}}
                 [:name [:first nil] :something [:a nil :b nil]])
{:something {:b "b", :a "a"}, :name {:first "john"}}
```

the syntax you propose will require a more complex implementation

Comment: edited. using `clojure.walk` would require a stateful construct of some sort and would likely be an absolute mess. I don't know of anything in `clojure.data.*` that would help here (`clojure.data` is a family of packages that each have their own repo etc.)